# Strings in Objective-C++

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, objective-c++

I just switched my code from Objective-C to Objective-C++. Everything goes swimmingly except for two lines.

```
NSString * text1=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",ymax] UTF8String];
```

This line complains that

```
error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'NSString*' in initialization
```

The second error related to the first is from the line:

```
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 2, 8, text1, strlen(text1));
```

It complains that

```
error: cannot convert 'NSString*' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'size_t strlen(const char*)'
```

Is there something I missed in the differences between ObjC and ObjC++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want:

```
const char * text1 = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", ymax] UTF8String];
```

Not:

```
NSString *text1 = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", ymax] UTF8String];
```

(Notice the return value of [-UTF8String](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String).)

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem, but why does NSString work in Obj-C?

Comment: Maybe because pointer conversion is more lenient in C. NSString * is a pointer, after all, char * is a pointer too, so they cast into one another with no warnings. That's what C++ was invented for, static type checking.

Comment: is there any need for try catch for this casting?

Answer (score 2):

But did you know that you can also just tell the NSString to draw itself, like so?

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", ymax];

//  Send a message to the string to draw itself at the given point with
//  the provided font.
//
[text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(20.0, 30.0)
         withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:36.0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a char * (which UTF8String returns) to an NSString *. This holds true for the general case; however, the C++ compiler is obviously stricter about it. It seems your code compiled by a mere stroke of luck; you want to move the UTF8String bit one statement down; `CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 2, 8, text1, strlen([text1 UTF8String]));`